# incompatible types androidx observer method

Tags: android, android-studio, mvvm, androidx, android-mvvm

I'm trying to figure out MVVM.I figured out how to observe LiveData using ViewModel. Now I encountered a problem.
private void subscribeObservers(){
mCharacterListViewModel.getCharacters().observe(this, new Observer<List>() {

```
          @Override
          public void onChanged(List<Character> characters) {
              if(characters!=null){
                  for(Character character: characters){
                      Log.d(TAG,"onChanged: " + character.getName());

                  }
              }
          }
      });
}
```

I am getting this error although I used correct types:

error: incompatible types: <anonymous Observer<List<com.example.rickmortycharacters.models.Character>>> cannot be converted to Observer<? super List<java.lang.Character>>
mCharacterListViewModel.getCharacters().observe(this, new Observer<List>() {

As I searched, I used the correct format in the code. In the past, Observer was in android.arch.lifecycle but now it is in androidx.lifecycle package. Should I use method instead of observe()? If yes, what should I use?

```
                                                            ^
```

Comment: instead of  `mCharacterListViewModel.getCharacters().observe(this, new Observer<List>() {` use `mCharacterListViewModel.getCharacters().observe(this, new Observer<List<Character>>() {`

Comment: I am still getting same error :(

Comment: Referring to the error message, there's a name conflict between `java.lang.Character` and your class `com.example.rickmortycharacters.models.Character` and you are importing the wrong Character class.  The best way to resolve this is to rename `com.example.rickmortycharacters.models.Character` class name to something that is not java keyword and then use that.